# using pragma pack (pop,1) with GCC

Tags: gcc, pragma

I've to use `#pragma pack(pop,1)` in GCC, but when I compile I receive this warning:

> malformed `‘#pragma pack(pop[, id])’` - ignored

Can anybody tell me if this is a good fix:

```
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma pack(1)
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What exactly do you think `pack(pop, 1)` should do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why would you want to use `#pragma pack(pop, 1)`?  What would that mean?

The normal use case is something like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // save current pack setting and set to 1

...

#pragma pack(pop)     // return to previous pack setting
```

Comment: I don't think that's legal code.  Just delete the `,1` from the `pop` directive.